# Spread invoice amount over months in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of jobs that have a start_date and end_date and invoiced_amount.

eg:

```
id, company_id, start_date,   end_date,   invoice_amount, billed_at
1,  200,        2014-07-01,   2014-09-10, 999.00,         2014-10-01
2,  202,        2014-08-01,   2014-08-10, 1400.00,        2014-10-01
```

I would like to select the share of each months invoiced amounts for a particular billed month (in this example October 2014) (eg if the first month is just half of the first month, then apportion the invoice amount) :

eg

```
id, company_id, 2014-07,   2014-08,   2014-09,  2014-10,  2014-11,  invoice_amount, billed_at
1,  200,        430.125,   430.125,   138.75,   0.00,     0.00,     999.00,         2014-10-01
2,  202,        0.00,      1400.00,   0.00,     0.00,     0.00,     1400.00,        2014-10-01
```

The date range could be quite variable and large but each month should be in its own column and the invoice amount should be apportioned depending on how many days in the month (with the first and last months days also taken into account (these could be halfway through the month for example))

Comment: I dont think you can make it into a column unless you want to make it fix only for that particular month. This is a very bad method for a dynamic database as it will increase and the month will keep adding

Comment: Good point @martonohalim  I've added a billed_at column and only query a subset of jobs for a particular billing month.  My main aim for this question is to see how to select that data.

Comment: Then how you add this 430.125 while from the table structure you didnt have the details for the invoice amount. Only the sum of the amount, or perhaps you have another child table?

Comment: @martonohalim I do have the full invoice amount.  eg invoice id 1 - 999.00.  It runs from 1 July 2014 to 10 Sep 2014.  So two full months and then a small part of third month.  So the 999 is split across those 3 months (first two more than the last one).

Comment: I am not sure how your algorithm split the invoice amount into 3 months like that. What my suggestion is you created a child table and put all the details, e.g July 2014 430.125, August 2014 430.125 and etc. Its easier to maintain, analyze and didnt take so much DB performance if you index it properly rather than making some cool algorithm to split it.

Comment: 430.125 is just created equally because july and august have the same amount of days, it would be different when the months would be january and february...tricky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its not quite the layout you wanted but maybe you could work with that

```
SELECT iv.*, 
       DATE_FORMAT(_date, '%M') AS month,
       COUNT(1) AS days, 
       ((iv.invoice_amount * count(1)) / (TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, iv.start_date, iv.end_date) + 1)) as monthly_amount
FROM (
        SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a) + (1000 * d.a) + (10000 * e.a)) DAY AS _date
        FROM (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS c
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS d
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS e
     ) a INNER JOIN invoice iv
WHERE _date BETWEEN iv.start_date AND iv.end_date
group by iv.id, MONTH(_date)
ORDER BY iv.id, MONTH(_date);
```

Comment: This is close.  Takes a very long time on my data set.  I'm starting to think I should restructure the db when saving an invoice and have a secondary table.